# PHP Unix timestamp

Tags: php, date, timestamp

I have a code but can't find where is an error. I have upcoming event and current time. If I convert my event to the timestamp it's less then current timestamp.  May be you can help me.

My code below:

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('Etc/GMT');

$upcoming       = "2012.09.05 23:50";
$current        = time();

echo "Upcoming: " . $upcoming . " | Timestamp:" .  mktime(23, 50, 0, 09, 05, intval(date("Y")));
echo "<br>Current: " . time();
echo "<br>Current SIM: " .  mktime(date("H"), date("i"), date("s"), date("m"), date("d"), date("Y"));


?>
```

Will output:

```
Upcoming: 2012.09.05 23:50 | Timestamp:1323129000
Current: 1346855221
Current SIM: 1346855220
```

Where Current > Upcoming timestamp. (???)
Thanks!

Comment: Yes. This string: date_default_timezone_set('Etc/GMT');

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you have 09 (with a preceding 0) this number is interpreted as an octal number, and so it's converted to 0.
Use: `mktime(23, 50, 0, 9, 5, intval(date("Y")));`

You can explore this "feature" a bit;

```
var_dump(9);   // int 9
var_dump(09);  // int 0
var_dump(07);  // int 7
var_dump(17);  // int 17
var_dump(017); // int 15
```

EDIT;

`date('n');` returns the month without leading zeros. And `date('j');` and `date('G');` return the day and hour without leading zeros. So you can change `mktime(date("H"), date("i"), date("s"), date("m"), date("d"), date("Y"));` to `mktime(date("G"), date("i"), date("s"), date("n"), date("j"), date("Y"));`

There's no way to get the number of minutes and seconds without leading zeros with `date()` so maybe you need to find another function for that.

EDIT:

To convert `2012.09.05 23:50` to a timestamp you can change the `.` to `/` and feed it to `strtotime()`:

```
$str = '2012.09.05 23:50';
$str = str_replace(".", "/", $str);
$timestamp = strtotime($str);
```

Comment: So how can I convert 09 to 9?

Comment: You have the 09 hardcoded in your code, so you can just change the code. Furthermore; `date('n');` returns the month without leading zeros. And `date('j');` returns the day without leading zeros

Comment: I can't use a date function as my string format is (2012.09.05 23:50) from .csv file. So I need to convert 09 and 05 to 9 and 5. Do you know how ca I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Leave away the unnecessary zeroes, that should do the trick.

mktime(23, 50, 0, 9, 5, intval(date("Y")));